# Using the (A*B) function in calculator- Pentaho spoon-

Tags: pentaho, data-integration, spoon

I'm trying since yesterday to use the function (A * B), very simple like operation, but it does not work.
Any help!
thank you.

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3XPAOxNJYxMfno0V0I3N21wblBhR1lyekhpNWlzb21XN2pHckJYRkdpSDNMX1NGT1hzQVk&usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post your code? And explain what 'does not work' mean.

Comment: I put a picture and the source file in the link above.

Comment: @user3600078 I can not access the links. No permission

Comment: oh sorry, you can now :)

Comment: OK cool I opened the ktr. Can you add some data samples for txt_nom.txt, txt_prix.txt and txt_ventes.txt. So that I can run it in my PC

Comment: Done! I put everything into one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following two additional steps `String operations` and `Select Values` to the same ktr.
[image]

In `String Operations` step do the following configurations.
[image]

And in `Select values` step use the below mentioned configurations in Meta-data tab.
[image]

And Finally in `Calculator` step you can use the value type as `BigNumber` and a conversion mask `#.#` for your new field `Total`.

**P.S**
There was a leading space in fields `Prix` and `Ventes` that had to remove using `String operations` step. That's why it failed in multiplication.

Comment: You don't need the String operations to trim whitespace, as long as you choose trim=Both on the XML input and choose the apropriate format string for those fields.

Comment: @nsousa He uses a `csv input` step to fetch data. There's no `XML input` step used here.

Comment: I misread from the screenshot above. But CSV input has the same trim options. If it's not set you'll probably end up with a leading white space.

Comment: @nsousa U mean the `Trim Type` field? There are (none,left,right,both) values? Will that trim the white spaces?

Comment: Left: trims white space at the left; Right: trims white space at the right; Both: trims white space at both left and right; None: doesn't trim white space. Which one to choose? It depends; where are the white spaces in those fields? Most likely left is enough, but both should also work.